# PHP: Split MySQLi results by value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Assume I have a database called 'products' with the fields 'id', 'desc', 'categ': (1, 'Banana', 'fruit'), (2, 'Apple', 'fruit'), (3, 'Tomato', 'vegetables'), (4, 'Water', 'drink').

How could I execute, or better: evaluate, a query on this database such that I can split the result into parts depending on their Category? My goal would be that I can insert some Headlines like

#### fruit:

Banana, Apple

#### vegetables:

tomato

and so on.

The basic code would be like

```
$con = mysqli_connect(/*etc.*/);
$result = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY `categ`');
mysqli_close($con);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // How to handle this?
}
```

Comment: In this kind of cases, I assign current category to a variable and check if current category equals to previous one at every step of loop. If it's different, I print category name as title.

Comment: Works, pse post as answer.

Comment: Sorry for being lazy :) Posted my approach as answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(/*etc.*/);
$result = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY `categ`');
mysqli_close($con);

//Assigning a temporary variable to hold current category
$previousCategory = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $thisCategory = $row['categ'];
  //Comparing this category with previous one
  if($thisCategory != $previousCategory) {
    //Printing category as title
    echo '<b>'.$thisCategory.':</b><br />';
  }
  //Printing product
  echo $row['product_name'].' ';

  //Now storing this category to compare with next one
  $previousCategory = $thisCategory;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but you could for instance collect all different categories in arrays for later display/manipulation:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    
  if ($row['categ'] == "fruit") $fruit_array[] = $row['desc'];
  elseif ($row['categ'] == "vegetables") $vegetable_array[] = $row['desc'];
  //etc...
}
```

And later you could:

```
echo "<h1>Fruit</h1>";
foreach ($fruit_array as $fruit) {
    echo $fruit."<br>";
} //etc...
```